# how to add custom selector on TableRow.? Same as lIstView's listSelector property

Tags: android, tablelayoutpanel, tablerow

I want the selector image for table row.. I was trying it from past few hours but i did't get any result for this..

I want the same property as listSelector in ListView for my TableRow. Is there any way to do such thing..??

Please hemp me out..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.androidpeople.com/tag/selector/) is an example of a selector with a button.  Apply the same method to the table row and you should be fine

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I tried that but it is not working for the table row. Its working good for button.. Do you have any other solution..?